# Fetch friend list from Google Plus

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, google-plus

I have login successfully with Google plus API in my iPhone App.Now i want to fetch my all friends with name ,id and birthday.
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: i didnt find anything for fetch my friends detail .For login i have used google plus API.

Answer (score 1):

Bad luck.. With my current experience google doesn't have any API's to retrieve data related to friends.

Refer these.

[How to fetch Google+ friends in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584822/how-to-fetch-google-plus-friends-in-android)

[google+ api person's friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683115/google-api-persons-friends)

[Get google plus user friends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820536/get-google-user-friends)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this API method?

queryForPeopleListWithUserId:collection:

Source: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people