# Does google return list of friends who are already using my app like facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, google-signin

In my app sign up is possible from both Facebook and Google. And there is a requirement for accessing friends list/contacts to check who are all my friends that are already using the app. Now, Facebook already returns the response as a list of friends who are using the app that I integrated the FB SDK in.

I want to know is there any way to get list of contacts that are already in my app using Google APIs? Or I have to fetch emails of my contacts from Google and manually check in my DB if they exist or not and decide on my on?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
Rahul

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239832/fetch-friend-list-from-google-plus

Comment: I have checked the documentation, and can retrieve list of contact from Google's people API, I just want to know if I can get the list of contacts that are already using my app which is possible in Facebook APIs. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the product manager for Google Sign-In. This is no way to get a list of users who already using a service ... you would have to request access to and fetch a full list of a user's contacts and check for existing users in your own database.